# Collection of good C++ Themes in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, themes, syntax-highlighting

I have found the site: http://studiostyl.es/ which specializes in Visual Studio 2010 themes. However, it appears that all of these themes are built with C# and .NET development in mind.

I am currently trying to get into some C++ programming and couldn't find anything on the subject of special themes for C++. Right now, almost all of my C++ code is a plain color and it looks like I might as well be writing it in notepad.

It may even be that I have my settings messed up and that those themes from studiostyles are supposed to be for all languages; I just started using Visual Studio.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: If you wanna dark theme - try this one http://studiostyl.es/schemes/amber-blue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) and don't look back.

Edit: There is also [Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/index.xml). As you can guess from the name, it's oriented primarily toward refactoring code, but if memory serves can also do some colorizing and such. I haven't used it recently enough to say much more than that (I've used VA-X for years, and a couple of years ago decided to look at alternatives, but after a month or two of testing, decided to stick with VA-X).

Comment: If no one responds with a free way in a couple of days, I'll mark this as the answer. That application looks amazing!

Comment: +1, VA-X really IS amazing. That is, if you configure it to your needs. The default settings kinda suck imho.

Answer (score 13):

No, the problem is that Visual Studio simply doesn't have anywhere near the built-in syntax highlighting support for C++ as it does for C# or VB.NET. *Some* syntax highlighting does work. For example, strings, comments, preprocessor directives, operators, numbers, and the built-in keywords all get their own colors. But a lot of your code will indeed be in one color ("Identifiers") if you don't lift a finger.

As Jerry suggests, [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) offers *far* better syntax highlighting than the default. But it's not free.

If you're like me and looking for a low-budget solution, you can [define your own keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8.aspx). This will at least make them show up in the color earmarked for "User Keywords". The link explains what you'll need to do in more detail, but it's really as simple as placing a plain-text file named "usertype.dat" in the Visual Studio application folder, and typing each of the custom keywords that you want to appear highlighted in their own color on a separate line. You'll have to restart the IDE for your changes to take effect.

Since you're using VS 2010, another free solution is the [Highlighterr for Visual C++](http://highlighterr.codeplex.com/) extension. This is one step up from defining your own keywords, and gets a little fancier with syntax highlighting. It takes advantage of the new Intellisense support in VS 2010 to turn on highlighting for classes, structs, macros, and typedefs. I haven't installed it yet myself because I'm still doing C++ development in VS 2008, but I'd very much like to try it out.

[image: side-by-side comparison with Highlighterr before and after]